# Handling subscription cancellations in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

If I understand it correctly -- both iOS and Android -- subscription cancellations are NOT handled in my app but in Settings and Play Store in iOS and Android respectively.

Two questions:

1. Am I understanding this correctly?
2. If that's the case, do we need to do anything in our apps such as provide instructions, etc?

Answer (score 0):

you need to deeplink from the app

android: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#deep-link

ios: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/handling_subscriptions_billing >> https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions
see `Enable Users to Manage Subscriptions`